# next js rootlayout different navbar for home page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

hi this is my code in next 14

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
return (
<html lang="en">
<body>
   <main>
      <Navbar/>
      {children}
   </main>
 </body>
</html>
)
}
```

To add conditional render, If I try to use useRouter it says it is only for the client. I can not use getServerSideProps either

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {}
```

How can I add a condition so that I am able to get a different navbar for home and for all other pages a different navbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new client component `NavbarContainer` and implement the conditional logic there.

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
return (
  <html lang="en">
    <body>
       <main>
          <NavbarContainer />
          {children}
       </main>
    </body>
  </html>
)
}
```

NavbarContainer component

```
'use client'

import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';

export default function NavbarContainer() {
    const pathname = usePathname(); // or useRouter();
    
    return pathname === '/home' ? <Navbar1 /> : <Navbar2 />
}
```